# Android Build for socket.io using intel xdk

Tags: android, socket.io, hybrid-mobile-app, intel-xdk

I use IntelXDK 2015 update for build my apps.

I build an app using "Cordova Hybrid Mobile App Platforms" for "Android Build" option but socket.io didn't worked.

However when I used "Legacy Hybrid Mobile App Platforms" for "Android Build" option, socket.io works

I haven't any idea why that happens

Thanks

Comment: do you have any errors in the console? give us something

Comment: can u post a simple example code that we can try?

Comment: Where is the "Legacy Hybrid Mobile App Platforms" ? I cannot find it (I use v2548)

Answer (score 1):

Have the same issue. The emulate and test through the intel app preview works like charm but when I build in to Android Cordova app I have the same problem. 
Also tried to use "Legacy Hybrid Mobile App Platforms" and works.

Comment: Not able to find option "Legacy Hybrid Mobile App Platform", also what is the solution for cordova app?